# Find the right change of variables for the following double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The double integral of interest is $\int \int _D \frac{2x^2 + y^2}{xy} dA$

With D lying in the first quadrant (upper right), bounded by the curves

$y = \sqrt{x} \\ y = 2\sqrt{x}\\x^2 +y^2 = 1\\x^2+y^2 = 4$

I tried so many different possible change of variables and none of them help me make the region of integration easier to describe. Can anyone help me with this ? Any help and insight is deeply appreciated

Comment: try to sketch above graph

Comment: The original region is a portion of a "donut", it's formed using 4 different equation, hence incredibly hard to describe directly. Hence I'm asking for help to find the right change of variable.

Comment: its not a donut its the concentric circle with two parabola intersecting them

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The occurrence of two equations of the form $x^2 + y^2 = C$ (for a constant $C$) suggest that we choose one coordinate to be $$v = x^2 + y^2 .$$ Choosing a second coordinate $u$ is only a little trickier---to do this, notice that the first two equations can be written in the form
$\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}} = B$ (for a constant $B$), which suggests setting $$u = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x}} .$$ By construction, this change of coordinates maps the region $D$ to a rectangle in the $uv$-plane.

Comment: I thought of that too at one point,  but I was hesitant as I cant be sure $\sqrt{x}$ is never 0. Hence perhaps you could correct my misconception here ?

Comment: @user2875613 Sketch the [graphs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsqrt(x),+y%3D2+sqrt(x),+y%3Dsqrt(1-x%5E2),+y%3Dsqrt(4-x%5E2))

Comment: Ok, I see where you are getting at now. I was thinking of this algebraically, but I neglect the fact that the region bounded contains only $x > 0$. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2875613 You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. Feel free to reply to my answer again if you could use more help with the question.